# Error in iTunes connect: The binary you uploaded was invalid. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist, info.plist

I went through the dev portal provisioning process twice now trying to get it to work, but to no avail.  I don't think it's the second half (signature is invalid), I think it actually may have to with my binary.  I have a warning in Xcode that isn't helping me because I don't know what to do about it.  And honestly I don't know how relevant this information even is.  But it says:

> "Check Dependencies: Warning: The copy bundle resources build phase contains target's info.plist"

The app runs perfectly in the simulator, and I haven't made any changes to the info.plist since I submitted the app to Apple last week. (this is an update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the warning, right click on the info.plist file and choose Get Info. Then from the Targets tab ensure that none of the targets (you may have only one target) are selected. You don't need to directly add the info.plist to the bundle. See this [Apple Q&A note](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2009/qa1649.html) for further details.

Check that you are building with the correct code signing identity. Right-click on your target and select Get Info. In the build tag look for the code signing section and ensure that the correct certificate is being selected for the application specified in your info.plist.

Then do a clean build (from the Xcode menu: Build->Clean and then Build). Check the build results (Build->Build results), you may have to change the settings to show All Messages. At the end of the build log you should then see a message about a successful codesign.

Comment: And that warning was apparently the problem that was keeping apple from accepting my app... THANKS!

Comment: In a newer version of Xcode (4.3.3), there is no Get Info in the menu opened by right clicking. Instead follow the Apple Q&A note link in this answer. To sum it up, go to your Target's Build Phases tab and remove your info.plist from the Copy Bundle Resources.